# Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter (LRO) stereographic projection transformation equations issues

Tags: coordinate-system, dem, elevation, moon, stereographic

I have been trying to figure out the coordinate frames the  [Lunar Orbiter Laser Altimeter (LOLA)](https://imbrium.mit.edu/) team uses for data.

In their [dsmap_polar.cat](https://imbrium.mit.edu/CATALOG/DSMAP_POLAR.CAT) file they state:

[image]

where λ is the longitude and X and Y are the respective Cartesian coordinates on the stereographic projection and

[image]

[image: $\theta_{\rm L}$] being the latitude.

The issue here is the meaning of their "longitude". The standard spherical system is defined:

[image]

where the angles are defined in the figure below. The standard chosen by LOLA is unusual as it seems to be rotated (they use the work by [Snyder](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395) I think). A significant issue arises when e.g. one wants to convert to gnomonic map. When I use the above standard spherical system, I do not get back to the same point from the gnomonic map.

I am looking for the motivation and explanation why would someone choose sine of longitude for x coordinate and cosine for y coordinate so that I can better understand what I have to change in my transformation equations.

Also, if one transforms from stereographic projection latitude longitude system as per their equations, does one really end up with x-axis pointing to mean-Earth direction?

---

### Detailed background

What I really need is to find the error in my conversion formulas. I need to be able to convert between LOLA stereographic projection and gnomonic projection. There are two major assumptions in all my (not necessarily the ones provided by the LOLA team) formulas, (x,y,z) is a right handed system and azimuth is measured from the x axis in counterclockwise (again right handed system).

Gnomonic to Cartesian planetocentric system (C1):

[image]

where hat values are the coordinates in Gnomonic projection.

Cartesian planetocentric to Cartesian stereographic projection (C2):

[image]

where the tilde values are Cartesian coordinates in stereographic projection and a is the reference lunar radius. The switched x and y in the numerator should reflect the LOLA team strange choice.

Now the inverse transformation are given by:

Stereographic Cartesian system to latitude longitude system (provided in the LOLA catalogue file for the norther hemisphere) (C3):

[image]

where

[image]

From latitude and logitude to gnomonic cartesian system (C4):

[image]

From here, latitude and longitude to cartesian planetocentric (x,y,z) is converted using the standard above.

Now, if i compare the results of the transformation (C1) and the (C3) converted to cartesian system by the standard above, the x and y axes are switched. The problem is, i am not sure which transformation is correct. What i really want is to be able to get to the planetocentric coordinates with x axis as mean earth direction because this from their own documentation, i understnad that this is the reference frame of choice, x points to the ME direction but with the transformation formulas it seems that after transforming from stereographic projection, it is y axis that points to the ME direction because it is the axis from which azimuthal angle is calculated.

---

### Specific numerical example

The code below uses Matlab syntax. a stands for the reference radius of the lunar sphere.
Let's start with some specific point in gnomonic projection:

```
a   =  1737400;
x_g = -411141.107140;
y_g = -411325.894877;
```

Now, convert this point from gnomonic coordinates to cartesian planetocentric which is derived using the standard spherical coordinates above:

```
x = x_g/sqrt( 1 + (x_g/a)^2 + (y_g/a)^2 );
y = y_g/sqrt( 1 + (x_g/a)^2 + (y_g/a)^2 );
z =   a/sqrt( 1 + (x_g/a)^2 + (y_g/a)^2 );
```

This gives:

```
(x,y,z) = (-389878.216487,-390053.447599,1647547.281362)
```

I continue to convert to stereographic projection using (note the interchanges x and y in the numerator on the right hand side which should bring one to the system of the LOLA team - hopefully):

```
x_s = 2*a*y/(a + z);
y_s = 2*a*x/(a + z);
```

which gives:

```
(x_s,y_s) = (-400407.334903,-400227.452318)
```

To check for consistency, I do the inverse transformation to make sure that i get the same point in gnomonic system. Taking this (x_s,y_s) point as a starting point, I convert it back to latitude,logitude system using official formulas of the LOLA team from the catalogue file above:

```
r   = sqrt(x_s^2 + y_s^2);
lon = atan2d(y_s,x_s);
lat = 90 - 2*atand(0.5*r/a);
```

and this results:

```
(lat,lon) = (71.492702,-135.012873)
```

Now, converting into cartesian system using:

```
theta = 90-lat;
phi   = lon;
x = a*sind(theta)*cosd(phi);
y = a*sind(theta)*sind(phi);
z = a*cosd(theta);
```

results in:

```
(x,y,z) = (-390053.447599,-389878.216487,1647547.281362)
```

You can now see that compared to the previous result that i got when converting from the gnomonic, here the x and y axes are interchanged here already. So i do not continue with the final transformations to gnomonic system. Also note that this is one specific point, so i am not sure, if generally, i only get interchanged x and y axes or for other points, other issues arise such as different signs.

---

[image]